# How to root LG K7 (MS330)?

Tags: rooting, root-access, lg

I have a cleaning program on my phone and one of the program functions is to optimize CPU.
When I try this, it says I do not have root privileges.

How can I get root privileges on my android LG MS330 ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting something similar to what @Gokul NC has suggested. I'm assuming you have a computer, so this is a better option with a higher chance of successfully rooting.

Access your computer, go to the browser, and download Kingo root from https://www.kingoapp.com. Once it's downloaded, install the program, connect your device, and you'll be given further instructions within the app. 
***I have tested this method more than 10 times, you should experience satisfying results.***

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Enable [Developers Options](http://www.andromods.com/basic-how-to/enable-android-usb-debugging-unknown-resources-gb-ics-jb.html) on the device & allow Unknown Sources to install the non Play Store app.
> 2. Download **[Kingroot app (apk)](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/one-click-root-tool-android-2-x-5-0-t3107461)** & install it.
> 3. Run the app & click “Try to Root” button to start rooting process.
> 4. Wait until it’s done, and your phone might reboot.
> 5. Your device is now rooted..
>
>    Optional: [You can replace KingUser app with SuperSU using **SuperSU-me app**](https://androidmtk.com/replace-kinguser-with-supersu)

Source: [XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/supersu/install-supersu-updated-binary-t3265663/post65003166#post65003166)

Comment: Kingroot is spyware. DO NOT download it.